# How to make SDK location for Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, location

I was following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvPJjQR3LJE and created the folder but when I want to select Android SDK install directory, I cannot find folder named "android-sdk" What should  I do to launch Android Studio then? Plesae help
[Selecting location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkspZ.png)
[Windows (C:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9QfT.png)

Comment: you don;t need to do anything with SDK location in Android Studio, it will download everything for you

Answer (score 0):

Hey do you check the folder is created or not because sometimes you got an error in CMD "you do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation" when you used mklink and then the folder is not created.
Might be this is the reason folder is not appearing because it is not created.

Comment: it does exist but when I want to open it there is "Localisation is not available"